# Call a function multiple times with more than one argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this function

```
function myFunction(a, b, c) {
    ... code here ...
}
```

Now I want to call it multiple times with several different arguments each time:

```
myFunction('sky', 'blue', 'air');
myFunction('tree', 'green', 'leaf');
myFunction('sun', 'yellow', 'light');
myFunction('fire', 'orange', 'heat');
myFunction('night', 'black', 'cold');
```

How can I merge all those calls in just one?

I know how to do it with iterations or `forEach` when there is just one argument, but I can't figure out how to do it with various non-numerical arguments.

Comment: That depends on your parameters, are they stored in an array? are they based on user input? Can you give some more context?

Comment: *"How can I merge all those calls in just one?"* You can't, if you mean a single call to `myFunction`, not without changing how `myFunction` works. Depending on where the values come from, you can certainly use a loop to only *code* a single call to `myFunction`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you change `myFunction`, you can't call it once and have it magically act as though it had been called five times.

You can *code* a single call in a loop, though, if the information you're for the arguments using is stored elsewhere.

For instance, if we assume an array of objets:

```
var data = [
    {a: 'sky', b: 'blue', c: 'air'},
    {a: 'tree', b: 'green', c: 'leaf'},
    {a: 'sun', b: 'yellow', c: 'light'},
    {a: 'fire', b: 'orange', c: 'heat'},
    {a: 'night', b: 'black', c: 'cold'}
]:
```

then

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    myFunction(entry.a, entry.b, entry.c);
});
```

Or if it's an array of arrays, we can use the nifty `Function#apply` function:

```
var data = [
    ['sky', 'blue', 'air'],
    ['tree', 'green', 'leaf'],
    ['sun', 'yellow', 'light'],
    ['fire', 'orange', 'heat'],
    ['night', 'black', 'cold']
]:
```

then:

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    myFunction.apply(null, entry);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
var values = [
    ['sky', 'blue', 'air'],
    ['tree', 'green', 'leaf'],
    ['sun', 'yellow', 'light'],
    ['fire', 'orange', 'heat'],
    ['night', 'black', 'cold']
];
values.forEach(function(args) { myFunction.apply(null, args); })
```

or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in ES6:

```
for (const args of values) myFunction(...args);
```

Answer (score 1):

lets suppose you already have an array with all the values:

```js
var colors = ['sky', 'blue', 'air', 'tree', 'green', 'leaf', 'sun', 'yellow', 'light', 'fire', 'orange', 'heat', 'night', 'black', 'cold'];

while(colors.length > 0){
  myFunction.apply(this, colors.splice(0,3)); //call the function with chunks of 3 elements
}
```